# sql server connection issue by using php

Tags: php, sql-server

I was using a PHP MVC framework called Yii and wanted to use mssql server 2008 as the database, but I encountered a connection issue and got the error information as following:

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] Db-library network communciations layer not loaded. (severity 9)

According to that I was thinking it has nothing todo with the framework but probably some sql server issues, I googled this issue and someone suggested to copy a dll file to system32 but did not work for me.

Please help me on this, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the Yii framework, but if it is using the php_mssql.dll extension, then you will also need the ntwdblib.dll file (a prerequisite for the mssql extension).
Can you confirm which PHP extension the Yii framework is using for SQL Server access and which DLL file you copied?

Comment: I figured out this issue myself, let me make a conclusion here and hope it can help other people won't spend too much time for similar issue like me.

1. Brian is right, we need to have ntwdblib.dll to be used in 3 places(THE DLL MUST BE THE SAME VERSION), windows/system32, php folder, apache/bin folder

2. If use mssql in Yii, in the config file(main.php), the db connection string, should use "... dbname=..", but not "... database=...", otherwise there will be a strange error(nothing todo with the db connection string) drive you crazy.